# Unit tests for firebase add using angular 2

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, firebase, angular

Does anyone know how to do a basic unit test using angular 2 to test a basic firebase add item.

I'm using typescript instead of basic JavaScript for my code

**This is what I'm testing:**

```
 export class AppComponent {
     ref: Firebase;
     refUsers: Firebase;
     refProfiles: Firebase;

     constructor(){
         this.ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com");
         this.refUsers = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com/users");
         this.refProfiles = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com/profiles");    
     }

     public addUser(newUser: Object): void{     
         this.refUsers.push(newUser, ()=>{

         });
     }
 }
```

**This is my current test:**

```
 import {it, iit, describe, expect, inject, injectAsync, beforeEachProviders, fakeAsync, tick } from 'angular2/testing';
 import { AppComponent } from '../app/app';

 describe('AppComponent', () => {

     it('saves an item to Firebase', () => {
         let refUsers = new Firebase('');

         let service = new AppComponent();

         spyOn(service.refUsers, 'push');
         service.addUser({ item: true });

         expect(service.refUsers.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
     })

 });
```

**This is the error I'm getting when I run that test:**

[image]

Comment: Seems like a configuration issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Three steps to begin testing.**

1. [Setup your testing environment](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/jasmine-testing-101.html). The Angular 2 docs have a great guide on doing so.
2. Write your code.
3. Write the test.

Let's say you create a class called `DataService`:

```
/// <reference path="typings/firebase/firebase.d.ts" />

export class DataService {
    ref: Firebase;
    constructor(theRef: Firebase) {
        this.ref = theRef;
    }
    add(object: any) {
        this.ref.push(object);
    }
}
```

To test it, you can import `DataService` and use Jasmine methods to test that the add method.

```
import {DataService} from './data-service';

describe('DataService', () => {

    it('saves an item to Firebase', () => {
        let ref = new Firebase('');
        let service = new DataService(ref);
        // create a spy to use if push is called
        spyOn(service.ref, 'push');
        service.add({ item: true });
        // expect that push was called
        expect(service.ref.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })

});
```

The key to testing Firebase methods is just to spy on them. You don't need to test that Firebase works, just that your code calls Firebase properly.

The problem here is that you're using the full Firebase SDK in your unit tests. Ideally you'd want to use a mocked library, so you can create a mock for whatever functionality you need from the Firebase SDK.

Comment: Hi David, I've added my code above eg my test and code I'm testing.
I seem to be getting a setup issue.

Comment: It seems you're not including all the files. This question though isn't about set up. We try to avoid turning one question into multiple ones. If you have another question please resolve this one and start another.

Comment: Okay no probs. I will create another question now.
This is the link to the next question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047379/unit-tests-for-firebase-files-not-included-issue