# Unit tests for Firebase - files not included issue (router 404 issue)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, firebase, angular

Unit tests for firebase - files not included issue.
I'm having trouble getting the unit test running.

The test code seems fine, but it seems some files are missing?

I'm using typescript instead of basic JavaScript for my code

**This is what I'm testing:**

```
 export class AppComponent {
     ref: Firebase;
     refUsers: Firebase;
     refProfiles: Firebase;

     constructor(){
         this.ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com");
         this.refUsers = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com/users");
         this.refProfiles = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com/profiles");    
     }

     public addUser(newUser: Object): void{     
         this.refUsers.push(newUser, ()=>{

         });
     }
 }
```

**This is my current test:**

```
 import {it, iit, describe, expect, inject, injectAsync, beforeEachProviders, fakeAsync, tick } from 'angular2/testing';
 import { AppComponent } from '../app/app';

 describe('AppComponent', () => {

     it('saves an item to Firebase', () => {
         let refUsers = new Firebase('');

         let service = new AppComponent();

         spyOn(service.refUsers, 'push');
         service.addUser({ item: true });

         expect(service.refUsers.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
     })

 });
```

**This is my index.html file (I think the issue is here):**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base href="/"></base>
     <title>Angular2</title>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.src.js"></script>

      <script>        
          System.config({
              transpiler: 'typescript',
              defaultJSExtensions: true
          });
      </script>

        <script src="angular2.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="router.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="http.js"></script>
        <script src="firebase/firebase.js"></script>  
    </head>

    <body class="container">
      <app></app>
      <script>
        System.import('app/app');
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**This is the error I'm getting when I run that test:**

[image]

**Karma config:**

```
 module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

basePath: '',

frameworks: ['jasmine'],

files: [
  // paths loaded by Karma
  {pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included: true, watched: true},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js', included: true, watched: true},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.js', included: true, watched: true},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js', included: true, watched: true},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js', included: true, watched: true},
  {pattern: 'src/firebase/firebase.js', included: true, watched: true},
  {pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true},

  // paths loaded via module imports
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},

  // paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
  // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

  // paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
],

// proxied base paths
proxies: {
  // required for component assests fetched by Angular's compiler
  "/app/": "/base/src/app/"
},

reporters: ['progress'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Chrome'],
singleRun: false
   })
 }
```

Comment: Does anyone know what the above error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the answer is.

I have a karma config issue basically.

I managed to get the unit tests to run by updated the patterns in the karma config files.

Comment: Great to hear that you've solved it. Can you add some more info on what you fixed in the config (note that your question doesn't contain any karma config), so that this answer will be more useful to other people that have a similar problem?

Comment: Yeh sure I will add it tomorrow for you

Comment: Hi Frank, I've added the config above fr you.